# MySQL Conditional Group_Concat

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I would like help with a conditional group_concat.

I have a table, Table1, with four columns (`id,day,class,results`). I would like to concat the results column by id and day and separate the concat into columns by class so the expected outcome would look like this:

```
id | day | class1 | class2 | class3 | class4 | class5 | class6

1 | Monday | APPL<br>TSLA<br>BRK | NKE<br>GOOG<br>ARKK | etc etc
1 | Tuesday | AGEN<br>MSFT<br>SBUX | BCE<br>S&P<br>FB | etc etc
```

I’m struggling with how to implement a WHERE clause so my results are currently ignoring class (see fiddle). I’ve tried multiple WHERE clauses and different combinations of GROUP By and can’t figure it out.

Here is my current code with just two class columns for simplicity:

```
SELECT id,day, (select (concat_ws('<br>',group_concat(results SEPARATOR '<br>')))
group by id,day) as class1,
(select (concat_ws('<br>',group_concat(results SEPARATOR '<br>')))
group by id,day) as class2
from Table1
group by id,day
order by field(day,'monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday')
```

Table1 Sample:

```
| id  | day     | class | results |
| --- | ------- | ----- | ------- |
| 1   | Monday  | 1     | APPL    |
| 1   | Monday  | 1     | TSLA    |
| 1   | Monday  | 1     | BRK     |
| 1   | Monday  | 2     | NKE     |
| 1   | Monday  | 2     | GOOG    |
| 1   | Monday  | 2     | ARKK    |
| 1   | Monday  | 3     | AGEN    |
| 1   | Monday  | 3     | MSFT    |
| 1   | Monday  | 3     | SBUX    |
| 1   | Monday  | 3     | BCE     |
| 1   | Tuesday | 1     | AGEN    |
| 1   | Tuesday | 1     | MSFT    |
| 1   | Tuesday | 1     | SBUX    |
| 1   | Tuesday | 2     | BCE     |
| 1   | Tuesday | 2     | S&P     |
| 1   | Tuesday | 2     | FB      |
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1drVtHD1wzsrLHFLJ2Lu1/5

Comment: This kind of thing is made wonderfully simple by means of the introduction of a tiny bit of application code. Also, just to note that, conventionally, the term 'id' is reserved for a surrogate Primary Key.

Comment: Do you have exactly 6 classes?

Comment: @radocaw, Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully it’s still achievable without application code.

Comment: @forpas. Yes, there are six classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, day,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN class = 1 THEN results END SEPARATOR '<br>') class1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN class = 2 THEN results END SEPARATOR '<br>') class2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN class = 3 THEN results END SEPARATOR '<br>') class3,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN class = 4 THEN results END SEPARATOR '<br>') class4,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN class = 5 THEN results END SEPARATOR '<br>') class5,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN class = 6 THEN results END SEPARATOR '<br>') class6
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id, day
ORDER BY FIELD(day,'monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1drVtHD1wzsrLHFLJ2Lu1/6).

Comment: Thank you! That’s perfect.